# Eigenstates/vectors of the sum of non-commuting Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, quantum-states

Suppose I have two Hamiltonians $H_1$ and $H_2$, and they're both two-level systems (they do not commute, such as pauli $X$ and $Z$). $H_1$ has eigenstates $|\psi_{11}\rangle$ and $|\psi_{12}\rangle$, with energy eigenvalues $E_{11}$ and $E_{12}$; $H_2$ has eigenstates $|\psi_{21}\rangle$ and $|\psi_{22}\rangle$, with energy eigenvalues $E_{21}$ and $E_{22}$. Now if I have a Hamiltonian:
$$
H=aH_1+bH_2
$$
How can I find the energy eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenstates? To me, I think one of the eigenvalues will be
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(E_{11}+E_{21})
$$
and the corresponding eigenstate is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(|\psi_{11}\rangle+|\psi_{21}\rangle)
$$
Is that correct? What if the plus sign is replaced by cdot? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Do you want to know specifically about the two-dimensional case or for a general case?

Comment: That is not correct. Your formulas give incorrect answers for the two limiting cases $a = 0$ and $b = 0$.

Comment: @Lucas Baldo Thanks for the comment! I'm concerning this 2-dimensional case but I really want to know a general case:)

Comment: There is no formula for the eigenvalues of $H_1+H_2$ in terms of only the eigenvalues of $H_1,H_2$ individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSWER - Parts I,II & III

---

$\texttt{C O N T E N T S}$

$\boldsymbol\S\texttt{ A. First step to answer}$

$\boldsymbol\S\texttt{ B. Towards a complete answer}$

$\boldsymbol\S\texttt{ C. Effort to solve analytically}$

$\boldsymbol\S\texttt{ D. Example}$

---

## ANSWER - Part I

$\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{A. First step to answer}$

As a first step to a complete answer I could say that the sum of the energy eigenvalues of the Hamiltonial  $H$ is
\begin{equation}
\texttt{sum of eigenvalues of } H  \boldsymbol{=} a_1\left(E_{11} \boldsymbol{+}E_{12}\right) \boldsymbol{+}a_2 \left(E_{21} \boldsymbol{+}E_{22}\right)
\tag{A-01}\label{A-01}   
\end{equation}
This is proved as follows : The matrix representations  of the Hamiltonians $\,H_1,H_2\,$ are

<sup>\begin{align}
H_1 & \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{11} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{12}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\texttt{ with respect to orthonormal basis } \mathfrak b_1\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}
\tag{A-02a}\label{A-02a} \\
H_2 & \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{21} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\texttt{ with respect to orthonormal basis } \mathfrak b_2\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}
\tag{A-02b}\label{A-02b}
\end{align}</sup>

For the matrix representation of $\,H=a_1H_1+a_2H_2\,$  we have

<sup>\begin{equation}
H\boldsymbol{\ne}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1E_{11}+a_2E_{21} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 &a_1E_{12}+a_2E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}a_1
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{11} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{12}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
+a_2
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{21} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-03}\label{A-03} 
\end{equation}</sup>

This is due to the fact that the two matrix representations are respect to different bases. That the wrong diagonal matrix to the left seems to have the correct sum of eigenvalues is accidental.

In order  for the linear combination of matrices  to be the correct representation of the relevant linear combination of the Hamilton operators we must express them with respect to the same common orthonormal basis, say $\, \mathfrak b\boldsymbol{=}\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}$.

So consider that $\,\mathrm U_\jmath\, (\jmath=1,2)$ is the unitary matrix for the basis change from $\,\mathfrak b_\jmath\,$ to $\,\mathfrak b$. Then for the matrix representations of $\,H_1,H_2\,$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$  we have
\begin{equation}
H'_1  \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U_1 H_1 \mathrm U^{*}_1\,, \qquad  H'_2  \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U_2 H_2 \mathrm U^{*}_2
\tag{A-04}\label{A-04}
\end{equation}
while for the matrix representation of $\,H\,$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$  we have
\begin{equation}
H'\boldsymbol{=}aH'_1  \boldsymbol{+}bH'_2\boldsymbol{=}a\left(\mathrm U_1 H_1 \mathrm U^{*}_1\right)\boldsymbol{+}b\left(\mathrm U_2 H_2 \mathrm U^{*}_2\right)
\tag{A-05}\label{A-05}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{align}
 \texttt{sum of eigenvalues of } H  &\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{Trace}\left(H'\right) \boldsymbol{=}a\mathrm{Trace}\left(H'_1\right)\boldsymbol{+}b\mathrm{Trace}\left(H'_2\right)
\nonumber\\
 & \boldsymbol{=}a\mathrm{Trace}\left(\mathrm U_1 H_1 \mathrm U^{*}_1\right)\boldsymbol{+}b\mathrm{Trace}\left(\mathrm U_2 H_2 \mathrm U^{*}_2\right)
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}a\mathrm{Trace}\left(H_1\right)\boldsymbol{+}b\mathrm{Trace}\left(H_2\right)
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}a \left(E_{11} \boldsymbol{+}E_{12}\right) \boldsymbol{+}b \left(E_{21} \boldsymbol{+}E_{22}\right) 
\tag{A-06}\label{A-06}
\end{align}
proving equation \eqref{A-01}.

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

$\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{B. Towards a complete answer}$

As referred in $\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{A}$ we'll represent the Hamilton operators by matrices with respect to a common basis. The given bases $\,\mathfrak b_1\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\},\mathfrak b_2\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}$  and the common basis $\, \mathfrak b\boldsymbol{=}\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}\,$ are assummed orthonormal so the properties
\begin{align}
\texttt{basis }\mathfrak b_1 & : \quad \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{11}\rangle \boldsymbol{=}1\,,\quad \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{12}\rangle \boldsymbol{=}0\,,\quad \langle\psi_{12}|\psi_{12}\rangle \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-01a}\label{B-01a}\\
\texttt{basis }\mathfrak b_2 & : \quad \langle\psi_{21}|\psi_{21}\rangle  \boldsymbol{=}1\,,\quad \langle\psi_{21}|\psi_{22}\rangle \boldsymbol{=}0\,,\quad \langle\psi_{22}|\psi_{22}\rangle \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-01b}\label{B-01b}\\
\texttt{basis }\mathfrak b\hphantom{_2} & : \quad \hphantom{_2}\langle\phi_1|\phi_1\rangle  \hphantom{_2}\boldsymbol{=}1\,,\quad \hphantom{_2}\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle\hphantom{_2} \boldsymbol{=}0\,,\quad \hphantom{_2}\langle\phi_2|\phi_2\rangle \hphantom{_2}\boldsymbol{=} 1
\tag{B-01c}\label{B-01c}
\end{align}

Now, the coordinate transformation from the basis $\,\mathfrak b_1\,$ to the basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$ is represented by a unitary matrix $\mathrm U_1 \in U(2)$. Without loss of generality we suppose a special unitary matrix $\mathrm U_1 \in SU(2)$. So
\begin{align}
 |\psi_{11}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}b_1\,|\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1}\,|\phi_2\rangle \qquad (b_1,h_1 \in \mathbb C)
\tag{B-02a}\label{B-02a}\\
 |\psi_{12}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}h_1\,|\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\overline{b_1}\,|\phi_2\rangle
\tag{B-02b}\label{B-02b}
\end{align}
with
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U_1 \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\in SU(2)\,, \quad b_1\overline{b_1}\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_1}\boldsymbol{=}|b_1|^2\boldsymbol{+}|h_1|^2\boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-03}\label{B-03}
\end{equation}
Also
\begin{equation} 
\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{-}1}_1 \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_1\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1} & \boldsymbol{-}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\in SU(2)
\tag{B-04}\label{B-04}
\end{equation}
For the matrix representation of $\,H_1\,$ with respect to the basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$ we have
\begin{align}
H'_1  & \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U_1 H_1 \mathrm U^{*}_1
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{11} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{12}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1} & \boldsymbol{-}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1E_{11} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_1E_{12}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1}E_{11} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1}E_{12}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1} & \boldsymbol{-}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
|b_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2E_{12} &\:\: & b_1\,h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{b_1}\,\overline{h_1}\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right) & \:\: & |h_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |b_1|^2E_{12} \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{B-05}\label{B-05}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation} 
\boxed{\:\: H'_1  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
|b_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2E_{12} &\:\: & b_1\,h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{b_1}\,\overline{h_1}\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right) & \:\: & |h_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |b_1|^2E_{12} \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\:\:}
\tag{B-06}\label{B-06}
\end{equation}
Note that the trace is invariant
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{Trace}\left(H'_1\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\left(|b_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2E_{12}\right) \boldsymbol{+}\left(|h_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |b_1|^2E_{12}\right)
\nonumber\\
 & \boldsymbol{=}\left(|b_1|^2\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2\right)E_{11} \boldsymbol{+}\left(|b_1|^2\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2\right)E_{12}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}E_{11}\boldsymbol{+}E_{12} \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{Trace}\left(H_1\right) 
\tag{B-07}\label{B-07} 
\end{align}

Similarly, the coordinate transformation from the basis $\,\mathfrak b_2\,$ to the basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$ is represented by a special unitary matrix $\mathrm U_2 \in SU(2)$
\begin{align}
 |\psi_{21}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}b_2\,|\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2}\,|\phi_2\rangle\qquad (b_2,h_2 \in \mathbb C)
\tag{B-08a}\label{B-08a} \\
 |\psi_{22}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}h_2\,|\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\overline{b_2}\,|\phi_2\rangle
\tag{B-08b}\label{B-08b}
\end{align}
with
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U_2 \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \in SU(2)\,, \quad b_2\overline{b_2}\boldsymbol{+}h_2\overline{h_2}\boldsymbol{=}|b_2|^2\boldsymbol{+}|h_2|^2\boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-09}\label{B-09}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} 
\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{-}1}_2 \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_2 \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2} & \boldsymbol{-}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \in SU(2)
\tag{B-10}\label{B-10} 
\end{equation}
For the matrix representation of $\,H_2\,$ with respect to the basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$ we have
\begin{align}
H'_2  & \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U_2 H_2 \mathrm U^{*}_2
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{21} & 0 \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
0 & E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2} & \boldsymbol{-}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2E_{21} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_2E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2}E_{21} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2}E_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2} & \boldsymbol{-}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
|b_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2E_{22} &\:\: & b_2\,h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{b_2}\,\overline{h_2}\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right) & \:\: & |h_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |b_2|^2E_{22} \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{B-11}\label{B-11}
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation} 
\boxed{\:\: H'_2  \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
|b_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2E_{22} &\:\: & b_2\,h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{b_2}\,\overline{h_2}\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right) & \:\: & |h_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |b_2|^2E_{22} \vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\:\:}
\tag{B-12}\label{B-12}
\end{equation}
The trace is invariant
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{Trace}\left(H'_2\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\left(|b_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2E_{22}\right) \boldsymbol{+}\left(|h_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |b_2|^2E_{22}\right)
\nonumber\\
 & \boldsymbol{=}\left(|b_2|^2\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2\right)E_{21} \boldsymbol{+}\left(|b_2|^2\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2\right)E_{22}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}E_{21}\boldsymbol{+}E_{22}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{Trace}\left(H_2\right) 
\tag{B-13}\label{B-13}
\end{align}

For the matrix representation with respect to the basis $\,\mathfrak b\,$ of the linear combination $H\boldsymbol{=} a_1\,H_1 \boldsymbol{+}a_2\,H_2$  we have from expressions \eqref{B-06},\eqref{B-12}
\begin{align}
 H' & \boldsymbol{=} a_1\,H'_1 \boldsymbol{+}a_2\,H'_2\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
q_{21} & q_{22}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \qquad (a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb R)
\tag{B-14a}\label{B-14a}\\
& \texttt{with}
\nonumber\\
q_{11} & \boldsymbol{=}a_1\left(|b_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |h_1|^2E_{12}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_2\left(|b_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |h_2|^2E_{22}\right)
\tag{B-14b}\label{B-14b}\\
q_{22} & \boldsymbol{=}a_1\left(|h_1|^2E_{11}\boldsymbol{+} |b_1|^2E_{12}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_2\left(|h_2|^2E_{21}\boldsymbol{+} |b_2|^2E_{22}\right)
\tag{B-14c}\label{B-14c}\\
q_{12} & \boldsymbol{=}a_1b_1h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_2b_2h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\overline{q_{21}}
\tag{B-14d}\label{B-14d} 
\end{align}
Note that for the trace we have
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{Trace}\left(H'\right)\boldsymbol{=}q_{11}\boldsymbol{+}q_{22}= a_1\left(E_{11} \boldsymbol{+}E_{12}\right) \boldsymbol{+}a_2 \left(E_{21} \boldsymbol{+}E_{22}\right)
\tag{B-15}\label{B-15}  
\end{equation}
as expected.

Now, the matrix $\,H'\,$ would be diagonal if $\,q_{12}\boldsymbol{=} 0 \,$ yielding
\begin{equation}
 q_{12}\boldsymbol{=} 0 \quad \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow} \quad a_1b_1h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_2b_2h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\boldsymbol{=} 0
\nonumber  
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
a_1b_1h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_2b_2h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\boldsymbol{=} 0
\tag{B-16}\label{B-16}  
\end{equation}

So if we could determine  four complex  numbers $b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2$ that satisfy among others the condition  \eqref{B-16}, then the elements of the basis $\, \mathfrak b\boldsymbol{=}\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}\,$ are the eigenstates of $\,H\,$ of eigenvalues $\,q_{11},q_{22}\,$ respectively. The eigenstates $\,|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\,$  are determined in terms of the elements of the basis $\,\mathfrak b_1\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}\,$ by inversion of equations  \eqref{B-02a}, \eqref{B-02b} using the values of $b_1,h_1$ or in terms of the elements of the basis $\,\mathfrak b_2\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}\,$ by inversion of equations  \eqref{B-08a}, \eqref{B-08b} using the values of $b_2,h_2$. The eigenvalues $\,q_{11}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\mathcal E_1\,$ and $\,q_{22}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\mathcal E_2\,$ are determined from equations \eqref{B-14b}, \eqref{B-14c} respectively using the values of $b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2$.

Now, the unknown 4 complex numbers $b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2$ are essentially 8 real parameters to be determined. We have till now 4 real equations : the reals \eqref{B-03}, \eqref{B-09}  and the complex \eqref{B-16}. We'll find in addition  4 real equations from the following scheme
that relates the special unitary transformations
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}}_{\mathfrak b_2}\quad \stackrel{\mathrm U_2}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad\underbrace{\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}}_{\mathfrak b}\quad \stackrel{\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{-}1}_1 \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_1}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad\underbrace{\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}}_{\mathfrak b_1}
\tag{B-17}\label{B-17}  
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}}_{\mathfrak b_2}\quad \stackrel{\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_1\mathrm U_2}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad\underbrace{\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}}_{\mathfrak b_1}
\tag{B-18}\label{B-18}  
\end{equation}

Since we have assumed that without loss of generality $\,\mathrm U_1,\mathrm U_2\,$ are special unitary, so does $\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_1\mathrm U_2\,$ that relates the initially given bases $\,\mathfrak b_1,\mathfrak b_2$. So

> *without loss of generality we assume that the initially given bases $\,\mathfrak b_1=\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}\,$ and $\,\mathfrak b_2=\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}\,$ are related by a special unitary transformation $\,\mathrm U$.*

(I believe that if this is not valid we could succeed it to be special playing the game with phases, that is using factors of unit complex numbers  $\,\rm e^{i\theta}$).

So, consider that
\begin{align}
 |\psi_{21}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}b\,|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h}\,|\psi_{12}\rangle\qquad (b,h \in \mathbb C)
\tag{B-19a}\label{B-19a}\\
 |\psi_{22}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}h\,|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\overline{b}\,|\psi_{12}\rangle
\tag{B-19b}\label{B-19b}
\end{align}
For the special unitary matrix $\,\mathrm U\,$ we have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\,, \quad b\overline{b}\boldsymbol{+}h\overline{h}\boldsymbol{=}|b|^2\boldsymbol{+}|h|^2\boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-20}\label{B-20}
\end{equation}
But
\begin{align}
\mathrm U  & \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm U^{*}_1\mathrm U_2
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1} & \boldsymbol{-}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline{b_1}b_2\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_2}  & \:\:\: \overline{b_1}h_2\boldsymbol{-}h_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{h_1}b_2\boldsymbol{-}b_1\overline{h_2}  & \:\:\: \overline{h_1}h_2\boldsymbol{+}b_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{B-21}\label{B-21}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline{b_1}b_2\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_2}  & \:\:\: \overline{b_1}h_2\boldsymbol{-}h_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\overline{h_1}b_2\boldsymbol{-}b_1\overline{h_2}  & \:\:\: \overline{h_1}h_2\boldsymbol{+}b_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{B-22}\label{B-22}
\end{equation}
Above equation \eqref{B-22} provide us with two more complex equations, that is with 4 real equations we are searching for
\begin{align}
 \overline{b_1}b_2\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_2} & \boldsymbol{=} b\stackrel{\eqref{B-19a}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=}} \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle
\tag{B-23a}\label{B-23a}\\
\overline{b_1}h_2\boldsymbol{-}h_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12} & \boldsymbol{=} h\stackrel{\eqref{B-19b}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=}} \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle
\tag{B-23b}\label{B-23b}
\end{align}

We repeat  below the 2 real and 3 complex equations  that $\,b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2\,$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
 b_1\overline{b_1}\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_1} & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-24a}\label{B-24a}\\
b_2\overline{b_2}\boldsymbol{+}h_2\overline{h_2} & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{B-24b}\label{B-24b}\\
\overline{b_1}b_2\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_2} & \boldsymbol{=}  \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle
\tag{B-24c}\label{B-24c}\\
\overline{b_1}h_2\boldsymbol{-}h_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12} & \boldsymbol{=} \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle
\tag{B-24d}\label{B-24d}\\
a_1b_1h_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right) & \boldsymbol{+}a_2b_2h_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)  \boldsymbol{=} 0
\tag{B-24e}\label{B-24e} 
\end{align}

This system doesn't have an analytic solution in general.

(to be continued in **ANSWER - Part II**)

Comment: @ZR-  : I elaborate  a complete answer and I think that I am on a  point close to the end.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful:)

Comment: @Frobenius -  I think it’s great (I upvoted before). Regarding the new parts in the revision, I would upvote twice if I could :)

Comment: @SG8  :  I will complete my answer and I'll try to elaborate an example.

Comment: @Frobenius - Wow!  Your answers are so complete (remember that quote from Herman Melville). I'm sure you already published several books (if not you should try it). :)

Answer (score 5):

No, linear algebra doesn't work like this. Since you mentioned these non-commuting Pauli matrices, just consider
$$
H=3\sigma_1+4\sigma_3= \begin{pmatrix} 4&3\\3&-4\end{pmatrix},
$$
with unnormalized eigenvectors:  $(3,1)^T$ for eigenvalue 5; and $(1,-3)^T$ for eigenvalue -5.

Your conjecture is false.

Answer (score 3):

(continued from **ANSWER - Part I**)

## ANSWER - Part II

$\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{C. Effort to solve analytically}$

So we have to solve a system of 8 real equations \eqref{B-24a}-\eqref{B-24e} with respect to 8 real unknowns, the real and imaginary parts of the 4 complex numbers $\,b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2$. For convenience this system is repeated below
\begin{align}
 b_1\overline{b_1}\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_1} & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{C-01a}\label{C-01a}\\
b_2\overline{b_2}\boldsymbol{+}h_2\overline{h_2} & \boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{C-01b}\label{C-01b}\\
\overline{b_1}b_2\boldsymbol{+}h_1\overline{h_2} & \boldsymbol{=}  \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{=} b
\tag{C-01c}\label{C-01c}\\
\overline{b_1}h_2\boldsymbol{-}h_1\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12} & \boldsymbol{=} \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle\boldsymbol{=} h
\tag{C-01d}\label{C-01d}\\
b_1h_1A_1  \boldsymbol{+}b_2h_2A_2 & \boldsymbol{=} 0
\tag{C-01e}\label{C-01e}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
A_1 & \boldsymbol{\equiv} a_1 \left(E_{12} \boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right) \in \mathbb{R} 
\tag{C-02a}\label{C-02a}\\
A_2 & \boldsymbol{\equiv}a_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right) \in \mathbb{R} 
\tag{C-02b}\label{C-02b}
\end{align}
We express the complex numbers in the following form
\begin{align}
b & \boldsymbol{=} \cos\omega\cdot \mathrm e^{i\beta}\,,\qquad  h \boldsymbol{=} \sin\omega\cdot \mathrm e^{i\gamma}\,, \qquad \:\:\:\:\omega \:\in \left[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right]
\nonumber\\
\cos\omega & \boldsymbol{=} |b|\boldsymbol{=}|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle| \,,\qquad \sin\omega \boldsymbol{=} |h|\boldsymbol{=}|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle|
\tag{C-03a}\label{C-03a}\\ 
b_1 & \boldsymbol{=} \cos\omega_1\cdot \mathrm e^{i\beta_1}\,,\quad  h_1 \boldsymbol{=} \sin\omega_1\cdot \mathrm e^{i\gamma_1}\,,\qquad \omega_1 \in \left[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right] 
\tag{C-03b}\label{C-03b}\\
b_2 & \boldsymbol{=} \cos\omega_2\cdot \mathrm e^{i\beta_2}\,,\quad  h_2 \boldsymbol{=} \sin\omega_2\cdot \mathrm e^{i\gamma_2}\,,\qquad \omega_2 \in \left[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}\right]
\tag{C-03c}\label{C-03c}
\end{align}
By these expressions equations \eqref{C-01a} and \eqref{C-01b} are satisfied automatically while equations \eqref{C-01c},\eqref{C-01d} and \eqref{C-01e} give respectively

<sup>\begin{align}
\eqref{C-01c} & \implies \quad
\cos\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{-}\beta_1\right)}\boldsymbol{+}\sin\omega_1\,\sin\omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right)}\boldsymbol{=}\cos\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\beta}
\tag{C-04a}\label{C-04a}\\
\eqref{C-01d} & \implies \quad
\cos\omega_1\,\sin \omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\left(\gamma_2\boldsymbol{-}\beta_1\right)}\boldsymbol{-}\sin\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right)}\boldsymbol{=}\sin\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\gamma}
\tag{C-04b}\label{C-04b}\\
\eqref{C-01e} & \implies \quad
\cos\omega_1\,\mathrm e^{i\beta_1}\sin\omega_1\,\mathrm e^{i\gamma_1}A_1 \boldsymbol{+}\cos\omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\beta_2}\sin\omega_2\,\mathrm e^{i\gamma_2}A_2\boldsymbol{=} 0
\tag{C-04c}\label{C-04c}
\end{align}</sup>

This is a system of 6 real equations with respect to 6 real unknowns $\omega_\jmath,\beta_\jmath,\gamma_\jmath\:\left(\jmath\boldsymbol{=}1,2\right)$. After a suitable arrangement they give respectively
\begin{align}
& \mathrm e^{i\left[\left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\dfrac{\cos\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\left[\beta\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{-}\sin\omega_1\,\sin\omega_2}{\cos\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2}
\tag{C-05a}\label{C-05a}\\
& \mathrm e^{i\left[\left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\dfrac{\sin\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\left[\gamma\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{+}\sin\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2}{\cos\omega_1\,\sin\omega_2}
\tag{C-05b}\label{C-05b}\\
&\mathrm e^{i\left[\left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right)\right]} \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{A_1\cos\omega_1\,\mathrm \sin\omega_1}{A_2\cos\omega_2\sin\omega_2} \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{A_1\sin2\omega_1 }{A_2\sin2\omega_2}\:\left( \in \mathbb{R}\right)
\tag{C-05c}\label{C-05c} 
\end{align}
Now, the rhs of \eqref{C-05c} is a real number so the  unit complex number of the lhs must be real yielding
\begin{align}
 \mathrm e^{i\left[\left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right)\right]}&\boldsymbol{=}\varepsilon_1\,\left(\boldsymbol{=\pm}1\right)
\tag{C-06a}\label{C-06a} \\
A_1\sin\left(2\omega_1\right) \boldsymbol{+}\varepsilon_1A_2\sin\left(2\omega_2\right) &\boldsymbol{=} 0
\tag{C-06b}\label{C-06b}
\end{align}
Inserting the value of equation \eqref{C-06a} in the lhs of \eqref{C-05b} we have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm e^{i\left[\beta\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\varepsilon_1\cos\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2\boldsymbol{+}\sin\omega_1\,\sin\omega_2}{\cos\omega}\:\left( \in \mathbb{R}\right)
\tag{C-07}\label{C-07}
\end{equation}
and by the same reasoning as before
\begin{align}
& \mathrm e^{i\left[\beta\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\varepsilon_2\,\left(\boldsymbol{=\pm}1\right)
\tag{C-08a}\label{C-08a}\\
&\cos\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\cos\omega
\tag{C-08b}\label{C-08b}
\end{align}
while inserting the value of equation \eqref{C-06a} in the lhs of \eqref{C-05a} we have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm e^{i\left[\gamma\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{\varepsilon_1\cos\omega_1\,\sin\omega_2\boldsymbol{-}\sin\omega_1\,\cos\omega_2}{\sin\omega}
\tag{C-09}\label{C-09}
\end{equation}
consequently
\begin{align}
& \mathrm e^{i\left[\gamma\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right)\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\varepsilon_3\,\left(\boldsymbol{=\pm}1\right)
\tag{C-10a}\label{C-10a}\\
&\boldsymbol{-}\sin\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \varepsilon_3\sin\omega
\tag{C-10b}\label{C-10b}
\end{align}
Our target now is by use of above relations to express $\sin2\omega_2$ in terms of trigonometric functions of  $\,\omega_1\,$ and $\,\omega$, insert this expression in equation \eqref{C-06b} and after that to solve with respect to functions of the unknown $\,\omega_1$. Multiplying \eqref{C-08b}, \eqref{C-10b} side by side we have $\sin\left(2\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_12\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3\sin2\omega$ so
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(2\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_12\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=}\sin\left(\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3 2\omega\right)
\tag{C-11}\label{C-11} 
\end{equation}
From above equation
\begin{align}
\left(2\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_12\omega_2\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm k\pi\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3 2\omega\right)\qquad \mathrm k\boldsymbol{=}0,1,2,3\dots
\nonumber\\ 
\boldsymbol{\implies}\:\varepsilon_12\omega_2 & \boldsymbol{=}2\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\left[\mathrm k\pi\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3 2\omega\right)\right]
\nonumber\\ 
\boldsymbol{\implies}\:\sin\left(\varepsilon_12\omega_2\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\sin\left(2\omega_1\right)\underbrace{\cos\left[\mathrm k\pi\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3 2\omega\right)\right]}_{\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\cos\left(2\omega\right)}
\nonumber\\ 
&\boldsymbol{-}\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)\underbrace{\sin\left[\mathrm k\pi\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3 2\omega\right)\right]}_{\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3\sin\left(2\omega\right)}
\tag{C-12}\label{C-12}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_1\sin\left(2\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}\cos\left(2\omega\right)\sin\left(2\omega_1\right)\boldsymbol{+}\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3\sin\left(2\omega\right)\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)
\tag{C-13}\label{C-13} 
\end{equation}
Inserting this expression in  \eqref{C-06b} we have
\begin{equation}
\tan\left(2\omega_1\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3A_2\sin\left(2\omega\right)}{A_1\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}A_2\cos\left(2\omega\right)}
\tag{C-14}\label{C-14} 
\end{equation}
We replace now  $A_1,A_2$ by their expressions \eqref{C-02a},\eqref{C-02b} respectively. Also note that
$\cos\omega\boldsymbol{=}|b|\boldsymbol{=}|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle|, \sin\omega\boldsymbol{=}|h|\boldsymbol{=}|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle|$ see equations \eqref{B-19a},\eqref{B-19b},\eqref{B-20}.


<sup>\begin{align}
\tan\left(2\omega_1\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{2\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3a_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle|\cdot|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle|}{a_1\left(E_{12}\boldsymbol{-}E_{11}\right)\boldsymbol{+}\left(\boldsymbol{-}1\right)^{\mathrm k}a_2\left(E_{22}\boldsymbol{-}E_{21}\right)\left(|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle|^2\boldsymbol{-}|\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle|^2\right)}
\tag{C-15}\label{C-15}\\
& \varepsilon_\jmath\boldsymbol{=\pm}1 \qquad \mathrm k\boldsymbol{=}0,1,2,3\dots
\nonumber
\end{align}</sup>

Using the plus/minus sign $\,\boldsymbol{\pm}\,$  instead of $\,\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3\,$ and setting arbitrarily $\rm k\boldsymbol{=}0$ we have

<sup>\begin{equation}
\tan\left(2\omega_{\color{red}{\bf 1}}\right)  \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2a_{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}\left(E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}\right)|\langle\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}|\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}\rangle|\cdot|\langle\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}|\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}2}\rangle|}{a_{\color{red}{\bf 1}}\left(E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}\left(E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}\right)\left(|\langle\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}|\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}\rangle|^2\boldsymbol{-}|\langle\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}|\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}2}\rangle|^2\right)}
\tag{C-16}\label{C-16}    
\end{equation}</sup>

So
\begin{equation}
\cos\left(2\omega_1\right) \boldsymbol{=\pm}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_1\right)}}\,, \qquad  \sin\left(2\omega_1\right) \boldsymbol{=\pm}\dfrac{\tan\left(2\omega_1\right)}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_1\right)}} 
\tag{C-17}\label{C-17}
\end{equation}
and consequently
\begin{equation}
|b_1|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_1 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)}{2}\,, \qquad
|h_1|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_1  \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)}{2}
\tag{C-18}\label{C-18}
\end{equation}
It's important here to note that because of the plus/minus sign $\,\boldsymbol{\pm}\,$ of $\,\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)\,$ in \eqref{C-17} we have two alternative pairs $\,\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2\right)$. A first one is with  $\,|b_1|^2<|h_1|^2\,$ and the second one is with $\,|b_1|^2\boldsymbol{>}|h_1|^2\,$ as follows

<sup>\begin{align}
&\texttt{pair 1: } |b_1|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_1 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{<}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_1 \boldsymbol{=}|h_1|^2  
\tag{C-19a}\label{C-19a} \\ 
&\texttt{pair 2: } |b_1|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_1 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{>}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_1 \boldsymbol{=}|h_1|^2  
\tag{C-19b}\label{C-19b} 
\end{align}</sup>

At this point we remind that this pair of coefficients is necessary for the determination of the eigenvalues $\,q_{11},q_{22}\,$ by equations \eqref{B-14b},\eqref{B-14c}. But for a complete determination of the eigenvalues $\,q_{11}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\mathcal E_1\,$ and $\,q_{22}\boldsymbol{\equiv}\mathcal E_2\,$ we need also $\,|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\,$ which in turn could be determined from  $\,\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)\,$  by equation similar to \eqref{C-17}. Now,

<sup>\begin{equation}
\tan\left(2\omega_{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}\right)  \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2a_{\color{red}{\bf 1}}\left(E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}\right)|\langle\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}|\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}\rangle|\cdot|\langle\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}|\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}2}\rangle|}{a_{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}\left(E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}\right)\boldsymbol{+}a_{\color{red}{\bf 1}}\left(E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}2}\boldsymbol{-}E_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}\right)\left(|\langle\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}|\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}1}\rangle|^2\boldsymbol{-}|\langle\psi_{{\color{blue}{\bf 2}}1}|\psi_{{\color{red}{\bf 1}}2}\rangle|^2\right)}  
\tag{C-20}\label{C-20}    
\end{equation}</sup>

This equation is produced from \eqref{C-16} under the following transposition of indices because of symmetry
\begin{equation}
{\color{red}{\bf 1}}\,\boldsymbol{\longleftrightarrow}\, {\color{blue}{\bf 2}}
\tag{C-21}\label{C-21}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
|b_2|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_2 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)}{2}\,, \qquad
|h_2|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_2  \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)}{2}
\tag{C-22}\label{C-22}
\end{equation}
Again we have here two alternatives pairs $\,\left(|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right)$

<sup>\begin{align}
&\texttt{pair 1: } |b_2|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_2 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{<}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_2 \boldsymbol{=}|h_2|^2  
\tag{C-23a}\label{C-23a} \\ 
&\texttt{pair 2: } |b_2|^2  \boldsymbol{=}\cos^2\omega_2 \boldsymbol{=}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{>}\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sin^2\omega_2 \boldsymbol{=}|h_2|^2  
\tag{C-23b}\label{C-23b} 
\end{align}</sup>

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{||c||} 
\hline\hline
\texttt{tetrad}\\
\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2,|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right)\\ 
\eqref{C-19a},\eqref{C-19b},\eqref{C-23a},\eqref{C-23b}\\
\hline\hline
\\
\left(\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\right)\\ 
\left(\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\right)\\ 
\\
\hline
\\
\left(\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\right)\\ 
\left(\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{-}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2},\dfrac{1{\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{+}}}|\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)|}{2}\right)\\ 
\\
\hline\hline
\end{array}
\tag{C-24}\label{C-24}
\end{equation}
In table \eqref{C-24} we see the 4 tetrads $\,\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2,|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right)$. Every tetrad if inserted in equations \eqref{B-14b}, \eqref{B-14c} produces a different $\underline{\rm ordered\: pair}$ of eigenvalues $\,\left(q_{11}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal E_1,q_{22}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal E_2\right)$. But an hermitian $\,2\times 2\,$ matrix has only one pair of eigenvalues. After a careful look we could verify that if the 1st tetrad produces a pair $\,\left(\mathcal E_1,\mathcal E_2\right)\,$ in this order then the 2nd tetrad produces the  pair $\,\left(\mathcal E_2,\mathcal E_1\right)\,$ in inverse order, that is these two tetrads produce the same $\underline{\rm set}$ of eigenvalues $\,\{\mathcal E_1,\mathcal E_2\}$. The same is true for the 3rd and 4rth tetrads : if the 3rd tetrad produces a pair $\,\left(\mathcal E'_1,\mathcal E'_2\right)\,$ in this order then the 4rth tetrad produces the  pair $\,\left(\mathcal E'_2,\mathcal E'_1\right)\,$ in inverse order, that is these two tetrads produce the same $\underline{\rm set}$ of eigenvalues $\,\{\mathcal E'_1,\mathcal E'_2\}$. The two sets are different in general :
\begin{equation}
\{\mathcal E'_1,\mathcal E'_2\}\boldsymbol{\ne}\{\mathcal E_1,\mathcal E_2\}
\tag{C-25}\label{C-25}
\end{equation}
Obviously we must reject one of the two tetrad pairs in table \eqref{C-24}. The top one or the bottom one. A good criterion would be their sum but unfortunately in any case, see equation \eqref{B-15}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal E'_1\boldsymbol{+}\mathcal E'_2\boldsymbol{=}a_1\left(E_{11} \boldsymbol{+}E_{12}\right) \boldsymbol{+}a_2 \left(E_{21} \boldsymbol{+}E_{22}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{+}\mathcal E_2
\tag{C-26}\label{C-26}
\end{equation}
After rejection of two tetrads we start from one of the two accepted tetrads to determine the complex numbers $\,\left(b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2\right)\,$  and consequently the eigenvectors $|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle$.

All this stuff would be clarified by an example.

(to be continued in **ANSWER - Part III**)

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer, that's really helpful!

Comment: Hey Frobenius, I think you are publishing another book :) Good luck in you way ...

Comment: @SG8 : Thanks !!! Good luck to you too...

Answer (score 3):

(continued from **ANSWER - Part II**)

## ANSWER - Part III

$\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{D. Example}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{||c|l|l||} 
\hline\hline
&&\\
\texttt{Hamiltonian}  & \:\: \texttt{eigenvalue} & \qquad\quad\texttt{eigenvector}\\
&&\\
\hline\hline
&&\\
& E_{11}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}3 & |\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
H_1 & & \\
& E_{12}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}6 & |\psi_{12}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
&&\\
\hline
&&\\
& E_{21}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}10 & |\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
H_2 & & \\
& E_{22}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}5 & |\psi_{22}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&&\\
\hline\hline
&&\\
& \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}\texttt{???} & |\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\texttt{???}
\\
H\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{3}H_1\boldsymbol{+}H_2 & & \\
\left(a_1\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{3}\,,a_2\boldsymbol{=}1 \right) & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=} \texttt{???} & |\phi_2\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\texttt{???} 
\\
&&\\
\hline
\end{array}
\tag{D-01}\label{D-01}
\end{equation}

This example is given in order to clarify the steps of the analytic solution presented in $\boldsymbol{\S}\:\textbf{C}$.

So, consider that the two Hamiltonian $\,H_1,H_2\,$ are given with the numerical data shown in the 1st and 2nd row respectively of table \eqref{D-01}. We want to find the eigenvalues and eigenstates of Hamiltonian $\,H\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{3}H_1\boldsymbol{+}H_2\,$ as shown in the 3rd row.

We start by verifying that the bases $\,\mathfrak b_1=\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}\,$ and $\,\mathfrak b_2=\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}\,$ are related by a special unitary transformation $\,\mathrm U$, that is
\begin{align}
 |\psi_{21}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}b\,|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h}\,|\psi_{12}\rangle
\tag{D-02a}\label{D-02a}\\
 |\psi_{22}\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}h\,|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\overline{b}\,|\psi_{12}\rangle
\tag{D-02b}\label{D-02b}
\end{align}
the special unitary matrix $\,\mathrm U\,$ being
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\,, \quad b\overline{b}\boldsymbol{+}h\overline{h}\boldsymbol{=}|b|^2\boldsymbol{+}|h|^2\boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{D-03}\label{D-03}
\end{equation}
see equations  \eqref{B-19a},\eqref{B-19b},\eqref{B-20}.

We have

<sup>\begin{align}
b & \boldsymbol{=}\langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{=} \:\:\,i\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\cos\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\beta}\,, \quad \beta\boldsymbol{=}\pi/2
\tag{D-04a}\label{D-04a}\\
h & \boldsymbol{=} \langle\psi_{11}|\psi_{22}\rangle\boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3 }{15}}\right)\boldsymbol{=} \sin\omega\,\mathrm e^{i\gamma}\,, \quad \:\gamma\boldsymbol{=}\pi
\tag{D-04b}\label{D-04b}\\
\cos\omega & \boldsymbol{=} \left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)\,, \quad  \sin\omega  \boldsymbol{=}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{15}}\right) \,, \quad \omega  \boldsymbol{=}0.06924 \texttt{ rad}\boldsymbol{=}3.97^{\rm o}
\tag{D-04c}\label{D-04c}
\end{align}</sup>

so
\begin{equation}
\mathrm U \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
i\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right) & \boldsymbol{-}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3 }{15}}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{i}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3 }{15}}\right) & \boldsymbol{-}i\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-05}\label{D-05}
\end{equation}
Inserting the given data of table \eqref{D-01} and the calculated coefficients $\,|b|,|h|\,$ in equations \eqref{C-16} and \eqref{C-20} we have respectively

<sup>\begin{align}
\tan\left(2\omega_1\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2\cdot 1\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{-}5\boldsymbol{-}10\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{15}}\right)}{\sqrt{3}\cdot\left(6\boldsymbol{+}3\right)\boldsymbol{+}1\cdot\left(-5\boldsymbol{-}10\right)\cdot\left[\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)^2\boldsymbol{-}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{15}}\right)^2\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}2\sqrt{2}    
\tag{D-06a}\label{D-06a}\\   
\tan\left(2\omega_2\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}\cdot\left(6\boldsymbol{+}3\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{15}}\right)}{1\cdot\left(\boldsymbol{-}5\boldsymbol{-}10\right)\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{3}\cdot\left(6\boldsymbol{+}3\right)\cdot\left[\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\boldsymbol{+}\sqrt{\tfrac{6}{15}}\right)^2\boldsymbol{-}\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{4}{15}}\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{15}}\right)^2\right]}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}2\sqrt{6}  
\tag{D-06b}\label{D-06b} 
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\cos\left(2\omega_1\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_1\right)}}\boldsymbol{=\pm}\frac13\,, \qquad  \sin\left(2\omega_1\right)    \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{\tan\left(2\omega_1\right)}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_1\right)}}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}
\tag{D-07a}\label{D-07a}\\
\cos\left(2\omega_2\right) & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_2\right)}}\boldsymbol{=\pm}\frac15\,, \qquad  \sin\left(2\omega_2\right)    \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{\tan\left(2\omega_2\right)}{\sqrt{1\boldsymbol{+}\tan^2\left(2\omega_2\right)}}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\dfrac{2\sqrt{6}}{5}
\tag{D-07b}\label{D-07b}
\end{align}
and consequently
\begin{align}
\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2\right)  &\boldsymbol{=}\left(\cos^2\omega_1,\sin^2\omega_1\right) \boldsymbol{=}\left[\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)}{2},\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}\cos\left(2\omega_1\right)}{2}\right]\boldsymbol{=} \left(\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{\pm}1/3}{2},\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{\mp}1/3}{2}\right)
\nonumber\\
& \implies \left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2\right) \boldsymbol{=}
\left.
\begin{cases}
\:\:\left(\frac23,\frac13\right)\\
\quad\texttt{or}\\  
\:\:\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)
\end{cases} 
\right\}
\tag{D-08a}\label{D-08a}\\
\left(|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right)  &\boldsymbol{=}\left(\cos^2\omega_2,\sin^2\omega_2\right) \boldsymbol{=}\left[\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{+}\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)}{2},\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{-}\cos\left(2\omega_2\right)}{2}\right]\boldsymbol{=} \left(\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{\pm}1/5}{2},\dfrac{1\boldsymbol{\mp}1/5}{2}\right)
\nonumber\\
& \implies \left(|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right) \boldsymbol{=}
\left.
\begin{cases}
\:\:\left(\frac35,\frac25\right)\\
\quad\texttt{or}\\  
\:\:\left(\frac25,\frac35\right)
\end{cases} 
\right\}
\tag{D-08b}\label{D-08b}  
\end{align}</sup>

We build now the following table \eqref{D-09} corresponding to table \eqref{C-24} of the general solution
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|l|l|} 
\hline  
&&\\
\texttt{tetrad}  & \:\: \texttt{eigenvalue}  & \:\: \texttt{eigenvalue} \\
\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2,|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right) & \hphantom{eigen} \mathcal E_1 & \hphantom{eigen} \mathcal E_2\\ 
\eqref{D-08a},\eqref{D-08b} &\hphantom{eig}\eqref{B-14b}  & \hphantom{eig}\eqref{B-14c}\\
\hline
&&\\
\left(\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac25\:,\:\dfrac35\:\right) &  \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}1 & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}4\\ 
\left(\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac35\:,\:\dfrac25\:\right)&  \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}4 & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=}3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}1\\ 
&&\\
\hline
&&\\
\left(\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac35\:,\:\dfrac25\:\right) &  \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}4 & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}1\\ 
\left(\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac25\:,\:\dfrac35\:\right)&  \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}1 & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=}3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}4\\ 
&&\\
\hline
\end{array}
\tag{D-09}\label{D-09}  
\end{equation}
We could easily verify the results discussed under the table  \eqref{C-24} : the 1st and 2nd tetrads produce the same set of eigenvalues
\begin{equation}
\{3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}1,\boldsymbol{+}4\} 
\tag{D-10}\label{D-10}  
\end{equation}
and similarly the 3rd and 4th tetrads produce the same set of eigenvalues
\begin{equation}
\{3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}4,\boldsymbol{+}1\} 
\tag{D-11}\label{D-11}  
\end{equation}
Note that the two sets are not equal
\begin{equation}
\{3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}1,\boldsymbol{+}4\}\boldsymbol{\ne}\{3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}4,\boldsymbol{+}1\} 
\tag{D-12}\label{D-12}  
\end{equation}
but in both cases the sum of the eigenvalues is the same : $3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}5$.

To decide which one of the tetrad pairs must be rejected we construct the following table

<sup>\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
&&&\\
\texttt{tetrad}  & \texttt{angle}  &  \texttt{angle} & \texttt{relation}\\
\left(|b_1|^2,|h_1|^2,|b_2|^2,|h_2|^2\right) & \omega_1 & \omega_2 & \texttt{to} \\ 
\eqref{D-08a},\eqref{D-08b} & \left(\arccos{|b_1|}\right) & \left(\arccos{|b_2|}\right) & \omega\\
\hline
&&&\\
\left(\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac25\:,\:\dfrac35\:\right) & \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}54.74^{\rm o} & \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}50.77 
^{\rm o} & \omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}3.97^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{=}\omega\\ 
\left(\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac35\:,\:\dfrac25\:\right) &  \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}35.26
^{\rm o}
& \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}39.23^{\rm o} & \omega_2\boldsymbol{-}\omega_1\boldsymbol{=}3.97^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{=}\omega\\ 
&&&\\
\hline
&&&\\
\left(\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac35\:,\:\dfrac25\:\right) & \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}54.74^{\rm o} & \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}39.23 
^{\rm o} & \omega_1\boldsymbol{+}\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}93.97^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{=}90^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{+}\omega\\ 
\left(\:\dfrac23\:,\:\dfrac13\:,\:\dfrac25\:,\:\dfrac35\:\right) &  \omega_1\boldsymbol{=}35.26 
^{\rm o}
& \omega_2\boldsymbol{=}50.77^{\rm o} &  \omega_1\boldsymbol{+}\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}86.03^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{=}90^{\rm o}\boldsymbol{-}\omega\\  
&&&\\
\hline
\end{array}
\tag{D-13}\label{D-13}
\end{equation}</sup>

From this table we conclude that the top tetrad pair produces angles $\,\omega_1,\omega_2\,$ with the following relation to $\,\omega\,$
\begin{equation}
|\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\omega_2|\boldsymbol{=}\omega
\tag{D-14}\label{D-14}
\end{equation}
while the bottom tetrad pair produces angles $\,\omega_1,\omega_2\,$ with the following relation to $\,\omega\,$
\begin{equation}
|\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{+}\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}90^{\rm o}|\boldsymbol{=}\omega
\tag{D-15}\label{D-15}
\end{equation}
But at this point we must remind equations \eqref{C-08b},\eqref{C-10b} repeated here for convenience
\begin{align}
&\cos\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2\cos\omega
\tag{D-16a}\label{D-16a}\\
\boldsymbol{-}&\,\sin\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\varepsilon_1\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \varepsilon_3\sin\omega
\tag{D-16b}\label{D-16b}
\end{align}
The relation \eqref{D-15} contradicts to both these relations for any choice of $\,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3\,$ so we reject the bottom pair of tetrads in table \eqref{D-13}  or \eqref{D-09}. If now we decide to continue  our analytic solution choosing the 1st tetrad of the accepted top tetrad pair then  $\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}\omega$ so
\begin{align}
&\cos\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \cos\omega
\tag{D-17a}\label{D-17a}\\
\boldsymbol{-}&\,\sin\left(\omega_1\boldsymbol{-}\omega_2\right)\boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\sin\omega
\tag{D-17b}\label{D-17b}
\end{align}
Comparing \eqref{D-16a},\eqref{D-16b} with \eqref{D-17a},\eqref{D-17b} respectively we must set
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_1\boldsymbol{=+}1\,,\quad \varepsilon_2\boldsymbol{=+}1\,,\quad \varepsilon_3\boldsymbol{=-}1
\tag{D-18}\label{D-18}
\end{equation}
To complete the solution we must determine the 4 complex numbers
$\,\left(b_1,h_1,b_2,h_2\right)$. Since we have their magnitudes, see the 1st tetrad in table \eqref{D-13}
\begin{align}
|b_1| & =\cos\omega_1\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac13}\,,\quad |h_1|=\sin\omega_1\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac23}
\tag{D-19a}\label{D-19a}\\
|b_2| & =\cos\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac25}\,,\quad |h_2|=\sin\omega_2\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac35}
\tag{D-19b}\label{D-19b}
\end{align}
we must determine the 4 parameters $\,\left(\beta_1,\gamma_1,\beta_2,\gamma_2\right)\,$ respectively, see equations \eqref{C-03b} and \eqref{C-03c}.

<sup>\begin{align}
\eqref{C-06a}\:\& \:\eqref{D-18} & \implies \left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right)=2\mathrm k_1\pi\,,\qquad \mathrm k_1=0,1,2,\cdots
\tag{D-20a}\label{D-20a}\\
\eqref{C-08a}\:\& \:\eqref{D-18} & \implies \beta\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right)=2\mathrm k_2\pi\,,\qquad \mathrm k_2=0,1,2,\cdots
\tag{D-20b}\label{D-20b}\\
\eqref{C-10a}\:\& \:\eqref{D-18} & \implies \gamma\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right)=\left(2\mathrm k_3+1\right)\pi\,,\qquad \mathrm k_3=0,1,2,\cdots
\tag{D-20c}\label{D-20c}
\end{align}</sup>

Choosing the minimum values $\,\mathrm k_1=\mathrm k_2=\mathrm k_3=0\,$ and given that $\,\beta=\pi/2,\gamma=\pi\,$ as shown in equations \eqref{D-04a},\eqref{D-04b} we have the following system of $\underline{\rm 3\: equations}$ with respect to $\underline{\rm 4\: unknowns}$ $\,\left(\beta_1,\gamma_1,\beta_2,\gamma_2\right)\,$
\begin{align}
 \left(\beta_2\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_2\right)\boldsymbol{-}\left(\beta_1\boldsymbol{+}\gamma_1\right) & =0
\tag{D-21a}\label{D-21a}\\
\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\gamma_2\right) & =\pi/2
\tag{D-21b}\label{D-21b}\\
\gamma\boldsymbol{-}\left(\gamma_1\boldsymbol{-}\beta_2\right) & = 0 
\tag{D-21c}\label{D-21c}
\end{align}
Setting freely $\,\beta_1=0\,$ we have
\begin{equation}
\beta_1=0\,,\quad \gamma_1=\pi/2\,,\quad\beta_2=\pi/2\,,\quad \gamma_2=0
\tag{D-22}\label{D-22}
\end{equation}
and finally the following complex numbers
\begin{align}
b_1 & \boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}\,,\quad h_1 \boldsymbol{=}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}
\tag{D-23a}\label{D-23a}\\
b_2 & \boldsymbol{=}i\sqrt{\tfrac25}\,,\quad h_2 \boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35}
\tag{D-23b}\label{D-23b} 
\end{align}
Consequently the following special unitary matrices, see equations \eqref{B-03} and \eqref{B-09}
\begin{align}
\mathrm U_1 & \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}i}\sqrt{\tfrac13} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}\:\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}i\sqrt{\tfrac23} & \hphantom{-i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}\:\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-24a}\label{D-24a}\\
\mathrm U_2 & \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_2 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}h_2\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_2} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_2}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}i\sqrt{\tfrac25} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}i}\sqrt{\tfrac35}\:\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35} & \boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac25}\:\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-24b}\label{D-24b} 
\end{align}
We could find the basis of eigenvectors $\,\mathfrak b\boldsymbol{=}\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}\,$ either from the basis $\,\mathfrak b_1\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\}\,$ by inversion of equations  \eqref{B-02a}, \eqref{B-02b} or alternatively from the basis $\,\mathfrak b_2\boldsymbol{=}\{|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle\}\,$ by inversion of equations  \eqref{B-08a}, \eqref{B-08b}. Note that using the former alternative we could write equations \eqref{B-02a}, \eqref{B-02b} formally as follows
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak b_1 
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
|\psi_{11}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
|\psi_{12}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:b_1 & \boldsymbol{-}\overline{h_1} \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\:h_1 & \hphantom{-}\overline{b_1}\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
|\phi_1\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
|\phi_2\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{\top}}_1\mathfrak b
\tag{D-25}\label{D-25}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak b\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{\top}}_1\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
\mathfrak b_1 
\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathrm U^{\boldsymbol{-}1}_1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\top}}
\mathfrak b_1 
\boldsymbol{=}
\left(\mathrm U^{*}_1\right)^{\boldsymbol{\top}}
\mathfrak b_1 
\boldsymbol{=}\overline{\mathrm U_1}\mathfrak b_1 
\tag{D-26}\label{D-26}
\end{equation}
Formally
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
|\phi_1\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
|\phi_2\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{b_1} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\overline{h_1} \vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\:\boldsymbol{-}h_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}b_1\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
|\psi_{11}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
|\psi_{12}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\tfrac13} & \boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23} \:\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
\:\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}\:\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
|\psi_{11}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}\\
|\psi_{12}\rangle\vphantom{\dfrac12}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-27}\label{D-27}
\end{equation}
and explicitly
\begin{align}
|\phi_1\rangle  & \boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23} |\psi_{12}\rangle
\tag{D-28a}\label{D-28a}\\
 |\phi_2\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}|\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac13} |\psi_{12}\rangle
\tag{D-28b}\label{D-28b}
\end{align}
Inserting the expressions of $\,|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\,$ from table \eqref{D-01}

<sup>\begin{align}
|\phi_1\rangle  & \boldsymbol{=}\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:i\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-29a}\label{D-29a}\\
 |\phi_2\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac23}
 \begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{+}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac13}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
-i\:\,\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-29b}\label{D-29b}
\end{align}</sup>

To the same results we end up if we start with the basis $\mathfrak b_2 $
\begin{align}
|\phi_1\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac25}|\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{+}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35} |\psi_{22}\rangle
\tag{D-30a}\label{D-30a}\\
|\phi_2\rangle  & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35}|\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac23} |\psi_{22}\rangle
\tag{D-30b}\label{D-30b}
\end{align}
that is

<sup>\begin{align}
|\phi_1\rangle  & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac25}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{+}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:i\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-31a}\label{D-31a}\\
 |\phi_2\rangle & \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\hphantom{i}\sqrt{\tfrac35}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac23} 
 \begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
-i\:\,\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-31b}\label{D-31b}
\end{align}</sup>

So
\begin{equation}
|\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:i\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\,, \quad  
|\phi_2\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
-i\:\,\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{D-32}\label{D-32}
\end{equation}
and in summary
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{||c|l|l||} 
\hline\hline
&&\\
\texttt{Hamiltonian}  & \:\: \texttt{eigenvalue} & \qquad\quad\texttt{eigenvector}\\
&&\\
\hline\hline
&&\\
& E_{11}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}3 & |\psi_{11}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
H_1 & & \\
& E_{12}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}6 & |\psi_{12}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\,\tfrac26\,}\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\,\tfrac16\,}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
&&\\
\hline
&&\\
& E_{21}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{+}10 & |\psi_{21}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
H_2 & & \\
& E_{22}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}5 & |\psi_{22}\rangle\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}}\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10} }\boldsymbol{-}i\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{10}}\boldsymbol{+}i\sqrt{\tfrac{3}{10}}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&&\\
\hline\hline
&&\\
& \mathcal E_1\boldsymbol{=}3\sqrt{3}\boldsymbol{+}1 & |\phi_1\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:i\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
H\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{3}H_1\boldsymbol{+}H_2 & & \\
\left(a_1\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{3}\,,a_2\boldsymbol{=}1 \right) & \mathcal E_2\boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{+}4 & |\phi_2\rangle\boldsymbol{=}\sqrt{\tfrac12}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
-i\:\,\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
&&\\
\hline
\end{array}
\tag{D-33}\label{D-33}
\end{equation}

> Not accidentally the normalized eigenvectors $\,|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\,$ in \eqref{D-32} are those of the
> $\,\sigma_2\,$ Pauli matrix
> \begin{equation}
> \sigma_2=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & \!\!\boldsymbol{-} i \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
> i & \!\!\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}} 0\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \tag{D-34}\label{D-34}
> \end{equation}
> of eigenvalues $\boldsymbol{+}1$ and $\boldsymbol{-}1$ respectively. This is due to the fact that I built the example by a $''$backwards$''$ procedure. At first I choosed these eigenvectors $\,|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\,$ as the resulting ones. Secondly I built two special unitary matrices $\,\rm U_1,\rm U_2\,$ represented by the simple expressions \eqref{D-24a}, \eqref{D-24b}. From  the normalized eigenvectors $\,|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\,$ as defined in equation \eqref{D-32} and the special unitary matrix $\,\rm U_1\,$ as defined  in equation \eqref{D-24a} I produced the pair of normalized vectors $\,|\psi_{11}\rangle,|\psi_{12}\rangle\,$,  I attached to them the eigenvalues $\,E_{11}=-3,E_{12}=+6\,$ so creating the Hamiltonian  $\,H_1\,$ as shown in the 1st row of the table \eqref{D-33}. Similarly from  the normalized eigenvectors $\,|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\,$ as defined in equation \eqref{D-32} and the special unitary matrix $\,\rm U_2\,$ as defined  in equation \eqref{D-24b} I produced the pair of normalized vectors $\,|\psi_{21}\rangle,|\psi_{22}\rangle$,  I attached to them the eigenvalues $\,E_{21}=+10,E_{22}=-5\,$ so creating the Hamiltonian  $\,H_2\,$ as shown in the 2nd row of the table \eqref{D-33}. Finally I gave the problem to myself to solve it $''$forwards$''$. This method teaches me very well to provide a detailed analytic solution.

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!\texttt{E N D}\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

Comment: Now, my laptop lags while scrolling to the bottom :)  Think about what will happen to my phone ?!!??

Comment: @SG8 : I'll complete my example in a few hours or tomorrow. I like very much good formatting and this costs in size and edit time.

Comment: God keep me from ever completing anything. H.M.

Answer (score 1):

Talking in general,
$$H^{(1)\otimes (2)}=a(H_1^{(1)}\otimes I^{(2)})+b(I^{(1)}\otimes H^{(2)}_2)$$
You can write eigenvalues equation
$$H^{(1)\otimes (2)}|E\rangle =E|E\rangle $$
$$(H^{(1)\otimes (2)}-E)|E\rangle =0$$
Writing
$$|E\rangle =\sum_{i,j}C_{ij}|E_{1i}\rangle \otimes |E_{2j}\rangle $$
and striking with $|E_{1m}\rangle\otimes |E_{2n}\rangle $ from the left
$$\left(\langle E_{1m}|\otimes  \langle  E_{2n}|\right)(H^{(1)\otimes (2)}-E)\sum_{i,j}C_{ij}|E_{1i}\rangle \otimes |E_{2j}\rangle=0$$
It looks quite complicated but it's not. The first term is just the matrix element of  Hamiltonian.

---

In the present case, the product space would be four-dimensional. So all you need to do is write the Hamiltonian in $4\times 4$ matrix and then solve the eigenvalue problem as usual.

Let's see one of the elements (I will suppress the notation):
$$\langle  E_{11},E_{21}|H|E_{11},E_{21}\rangle =\langle  E_{11},E_{21}|aH_1+bH_2|E_{11},E_{21}\rangle$$
$$=a\langle  E_{11},E_{21}|H_1|E_{11},E_{21}\rangle+b\langle  E_{11},E_{21}|H_2|E_{11},E_{21}\rangle=aE_1+bE_2$$

Comment: I don't think that the question concerns product spaces, states, transformations.